# Propagate events to both QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, events

I have a Qt app with a QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene. I subclassed them both and want to handle mouseevents in both. I can do this for both classes separately, using

```
     virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event);
```

But when I handle the events in the GraphicsView, I don't receive them anymore in the GraphicsScene. How do I fix this, i.e. pass the event from the grapchicsview to the graphicsscene?

Answer (score 4):

Just forward `mousePressEvent` to your `GraphicsView`'s parent, this will then call scene's `mousePressEvent` :

```
void MyGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * e)
{
    // forward to scene (via default view behaviour)
    QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(e) ;
    // ...
}
```

BTW, `QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent` has a different kind (class) of event : `QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent`

Answer (score 1):

Call the base implementation at the end of your overriden function, eg:

```
void MyView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
   // do something
   QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(event);
}
```